# How to bind enumerate variable changed in objc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, reactive-cocoa

I'm ready to migrate my project to RAC,but there is a error that when I want to bind a property's change.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface XBXMLoginTextField : UIView
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIKeyboardType keyboardType;
@end
```

In .m file:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        [RACObserve(self, keyboardType) subscribeNext:^(UIKeyboardType x) {

        }];
    }
    return self;
}
```

There is an error ->
Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(UIKeyboardType)' to parameter of type 'void (^ _Nonnull)(id  _Nullable __strong)'

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RACObserve` returns a signal that fires its integer value as a boxed `NSNumber *`, so you need to make use of its `integerValue`:

```
[RACObserve(self, keyboardType) subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *keyboardType) {
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)keyboardType.integerValue);

    // Or any other user of keyboardType.integerValue, such as:
    if (keyboardType.integerValue == UIKeyboardTypeURL) {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}];
```

Comment: Awesome! You help me a lot.Thank you very much! Wish you have a good time for the comming Christmas!